# Adding new class to existing apk

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm noobs in android programming,anyway I was success to build my first application using eclipse and my question is...is it possible to decompile my new `apk` and put the classes and paste to another apk using extend button to call it's activity?if yes,can someone explain me how to implement that?

Thanks for the answers

[Solved]

Comment: You can always add your class to eclipse and generate new apk.

Comment: In my case ,i wanna add my new class from my new apk to systemui.apk,and using extend button in xml to call it's class

Comment: the apk file is a complete android applications, it includes systemui and anything else you want inside your app, if you want to organize them you can use libraries. If you want to add things to your application add them to eclipse/android-studio/project folder and re-build your apk

Comment: So..shall i use the full java resources of systemui then build it in eclipse?i'm a mediatek user and the android developers doesn't share it resources to user ,sir..is there any easiest way?